# Identifying starting date of a period with low values in a time series in R

Tags: r, date, time-series

I'm quite new to time series and I am wondering what is the best way to identify the starting date of a period with low values of a variable. So in this example I would in a first step want to i) identify whether there is such a period of let's say at least 5 values that are similarly low and ii) what the starting date of this period is.

So in this example (https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxLQg.png) for the first 3 individuals (c15793, c15798 and c3556) I want to figure out that there is such a period and that the starting date is on the 20th of May for c15798 and on the 22nd of May for the other two. But c5157 should be identified as not having such a period.

I have no clue on how I could identify such a period and I was hoping someone would have an idea and point me to a method or a point where I could start. Everything I can think of would require some sort of threshold (e.g. the difference between consecutive measurements) which I don't know how to choose. So if anyone has a more elegant idea or a good idea on how to set a threshold, I would be more than happy to learn about it.

Thanks so much in advance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzD6G.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The hard part is to define a "period with low values". I think this could be done by some clustering techniqe.

Comment: Are you trying to find the trend and specifically where the trend is downward and the minimum of that?

Comment: Hi thanks for your comments. I am trying to find the trend, but not the minimal value of the trend but the earliest date of when the trend starts.